# Can I locate tables based on a column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working without documentation we have a dental system that displays the status of an appointment. 
I have to report on who scheduled the appt. and who confirmed. The systems displays this as 'FIRM' and 'FIXED. I have located how they store the person who scheduled the appt. but not who has confirmed it.

But since they use 'FIRM" is there a way I can locate which tables have this value? we are running sql server 2008.

Comment: I don't follow your question entirely.  Can you add some data?

Comment: do you want to find out which table has a column named `FIRM`?

Comment: no values sorry it wasnt clear. data values

Comment: basically you are saying some table has a column with value 'Firm' and you want to find that table??

Comment: Just poke around your tables in your DBMS and find something named like what you're looking for... like a table named "Schedule", "Appointments", "Status", "Confirmations"...

Comment: can't figure out what you are asking. Why don't you add some sample data and expected result

Comment: And if the system is normalized you should only find that value in one table, the one that is the list of possible values for an appointment status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find out the table name which have column name like FIRM by using below query -

```
select * from information_schema.columns where column_name like '%FIRM%'
```

if you want to know where this column is referred (like in SP , trigger or view) or a or hard coded value is used to display, you can use below query-

```
select distinct object_name(id) from syscomments  where text like '%FIRM%'
```